# Apache airflow performance degradation

Tags: performance, airflow

I have an instance of airflow on a kubernetes cluster on GKE using a CloudSql db on GCP.
It handle 7 DAG.

3 linked dags are the main problem :

- ListToApi - Get a list and trigger 1 dagrun of ApiToExport for each line
- ApiToExport - Save each request and trigger 1 dagrun of Export
- Export - Export data and save results

Each day it handle a list of 500 rows. So :

- 1 ListToApi
- 500 ApiToExport
- 500 Export

After 1 month i reached near 25000 DagRun. And performances are bad.
Inspecting queries i've found one query that list dagruns :

```sql
SELECT
  dag_run.state,
  dag_run.id,
  ...
  dag_run.updated_at
FROM
  dag_run
WHERE
  dag_run.dag_id = $1
  AND dag_run.execution_date < $2::timestamptz
  AND dag_run.state = $3
ORDER BY
  dag_run.execution_date DESC
```

This query took 2 seconds, return an avg of 7000 rows and is executed near every seconds.
I thinks that cleaning up dagrun history will help, but i need to access to execution history.
Potentially i will need to run 5000 rows each day.

How could i manage a history of dagrun without impacting on performance ?
Where is this query used ? How can i disable it ?

Thank you

Comment: you may need to increase the size of your db

Comment: You can either leverage `airflow db clean` command that purges old records: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.4.3/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#clean
or you can use Google's manual: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/cleanup-airflow-database

Answer (score 0):

I've found the source of the problem.
It was an update to airflow 2.7 that added this problem. With airflow 2.7.1 they solved the issue adding a LIMIT to the query.

https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/33688